# NHibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve property with WebApi + ODaa

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, odata

When I use a filter on my Url as GET `/api/modalidades?$orderby=Nome&$select=Nome,Id` an error is displayed!

### Packages:

> FluentNHibernate               1.3.0.733
>   NHibernate                     3.3.3.4000
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi        5.0.0-rtm-130624
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0-rtm-130624
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core   5.0.0-rtm-130624
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData  5.0.0-rtm-130624
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web... 5.0.0-rtm-130624

### Code

#### Domain

```
public class Modalidade : EntityNome
{ }
public abstract class EntityNome : IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected internal set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    [Required]
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
}
public interface IEntity : IKeyed<int>
{
}
public interface IKeyed<T> where T : struct
{
    T Id { get; }
}
```

#### Web

**WebApiConfig.css**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Modalidade>("modalidades");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Modalidade>()
        .DerivesFrom<EntityNome>()
        .Property(p => p.Id);

    var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

    config.Routes.MapODataRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "api", model: model);

    config.EnableQuerySupport();

    var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    var enumConverter = new StringEnumConverter();
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(enumConverter);

    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    var jqueryFormatter = config.Formatters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(JQueryMvcFormUrlEncodedFormatter));
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter);
    config.Formatters.Remove(jqueryFormatter);
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
}
```

**Controllers**

```
public class baseApiController<T> : EntitySetController<T, int>
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    public IRepository<T> Repositorio { get; private set; }

    public baseApiController(IRepository<T> repositorio)
    {
        Repositorio = repositorio;
    }

    [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, PageSize = 20)]
    public override IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return Repositorio.All();
    }

    [HttpGet, Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    protected override T GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return Repositorio.Get(key);
    }
}

[Authorize]
public class modalidadesController : baseApiController<Modalidade>
{
    public modalidadesController(IModalidadeRepository repositorio)
        : base(repositorio)
    { }
}
```

### Error

When no filter is applied, everything works. But when a filter is applied, an error is generated!

> GET /api/modalidades?$orderby=Nome&$select=Nome,Id HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:49971
>   Cache-Control: no-cache

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "An error has occurred."
        },
        "innererror": {
            "message": "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.",
            "type": "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException",
            "stacktrace": "   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
            "internalexception": {
                "message": "could not resolve property: class of: CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Modalidade [.Take[System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandWrapper`1[[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Modalidade, CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]](.Select[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Modalidade,System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandWrapper`1[[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Modalidade, CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]](.ThenBy[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Modalidade,System.Int32](.OrderBy[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Modalidade,System.String](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.Modalidade], Quote(($it, ) => ($it.Nome)), ), Quote(($it, ) => ($it.Id)), ), Quote((, ) => (new SelectExpandWrapper`1()444fb09a-b4c8-43e1-b1f6-d469f9da76eanew NamedPropertyWithNext`1()IdEqual(, NULL) ? NULL : Convert(.Id)new NamedProperty`1()IsType(, CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.EntityNome) ? Nome : NULLEqual(, NULL) ? NULL : IsType(, CreditoImobiliarioBB.Model.EntityNome) ? TypeAs().Nome : NULL)), ), p8, )]",
                "type": "NHibernate.QueryException",
                "stacktrace": "   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.ToType(String propertyName)\r\n   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.ToType(String propertyName)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElementType.GetPropertyType(String propertyName, String propertyPath)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElement.GetPropertyType(String propertyName, String propertyPath)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.DotNode.GetDataType()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.DotNode.PrepareLhs()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.DotNode.Resolve(Boolean generateJoin, Boolean implicitJoin, String classAlias, IASTNode parent)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromReferenceNode.Resolve(Boolean generateJoin, Boolean implicitJoin, String classAlias)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromReferenceNode.Resolve(Boolean generateJoin, Boolean implicitJoin)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.Resolve(IASTNode node)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.expr()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.exprOrSubquery()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.comparisonExpr()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.logicalExpr()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.caseExpr()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.arithmeticExpr()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectExpr()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectExprList()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectClause()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.unionedQuery()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.query()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectStatement()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.statement()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(String collectionRole)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)\r\n   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)\r\n   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)\r\n   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean& resultsLimited)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $select part of the query is the troubling one. We haven't tried to get $select and $expand working with anything other than Linq2Objects and Entityframework. The expression that we generate to get $select and $expand working and in an efficient manner with Entityframework is non-trivial.

That said, one solution to your problem is to take ODataQueryOptions and apply the query in parts. Apply the $filter, $orderby, $skip, $top in the database and then apply $select and $expand in-memory by doing a ToList() after the first step.

I will play further with nhibernate to see if we can improve our expression generation to get this scenario working.

Comment: I'm using `EntitySetController`and does not even have a method with `ODataQueryOptions` to overwrite.   When I use `ApiController` works.

Comment: How can I apply `$select` and `$expand` in memory? I tried to use `QueryOptions` and apply `$filter, $orderby, $skip, $top` but  `.ToList` does not override in the `EntitySetController`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `EnsureStableOrdering = false` to your `QueryableAttribute`:

```
[Queryable(EnsureStableOrdering = false, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, PageSize = 20)]
public override IQueryable<T> Get()
```